# Get shared preferences inside PageAdapter?

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a home replacement app. I need to get shared preferences inside my PageAdapter so I can change icon size and a couple of other aspects of the launcher.

When using:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
        Context context = container.getContext();
```

Eclipse tells me method getDefaultSharedPreferences is not defined for type PageAdapter.

Is there any way to do it somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use correct Context: Replace "this" with correct Context.

Comment: thanks, that worked. Is it possible to make it work directly on the PagerAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

From the activity that creates an object of this PagerAdapter, pass the settings that you want this PagerAdapter to have through a method (or maybe the constructor)